# Commiting files to SVN using PHP - one function, two pages and two different result

Tags: php, svn

My problem is that I'm calling the same function using two different pages (located in different folders) and getting two different results. The goal is to submit content in a textarea, save it to a file and then commit this file.

Here is my file structure

```
\svntest\folio\00123\svn.php
\svntest\folio\00456\my_file.php
\svntest\test.php
\svntest\svncmd\commit.bat
```

The content of commit.bat

```
svn ci -m "hello" %1
```

The content of \svntest\folio\00123\svn.php:

```
if($_POST){

    if( strlen($_POST['show_revision']) ){

        $f = dirname(__FILE__);
        $f .= '\\..\\..\\'.$file;
        svn_save_file($_POST['show_revision'], $f);

        svn_commit_file();
    }

    //header('location: svn.php');
}


<form method="post">
<fieldset><legend>Page Content</legend>
<div>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="txtarea" name="txtarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Save"/></div>
</form>
```

The content of \svntest\test.php:

```
svn_commit_file();
```

The function svn_commit_file():

```
function svn_commit_file(){
    $cmd = '"C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Desktop\\xampp\\htdocs\\xampp\\LearnPHP\\svntest\\svncmd\\commit.bat" "folio\\00456\\my_file.php"';
    $out = system($cmd, $r);
}
```

**What doesn't work**

file: \svntest\folio\00123\svn.php

result: no svn commit message, nothing gets output from the system() call...

**What works**

file: \svntest\test.php

result: svn commit message is obtained and version added to SVN

Since everything is hardcoded in svn_commit_file(), I fail to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Let's see your `include` / `require` statements.

Comment: I'm assuming there are some `<?php` `?>` tags in `\svntest\folio\00123\svn.php`? If not, add them, if there are please show them in your code - it's very hard to debug code that wouldn't even parse as PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should specify an absolute path for your file to be checked in. The current working directory differs between `test.php` and `folio\00123\svn.php`.

```
function svn_commit_file(){
    $cmd = '"C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Desktop\\xampp\\htdocs\\xampp\\LearnPHP\\svntest\\svncmd\\commit.bat" "C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Desktop\\xampp\\htdocs\\xampp\\LearnPHP\\svntest\\folio\\00456\\my_file.php"';
    $out = system($cmd, $r);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do this. I thought that everything needed to come relative to the working directory. In my case, the checkout destination was svntest. Does this mean I could commit any file outside of the working directory and it would replicate the folder hiearchy inside the working directory/repo?

Comment: how is this even working then? The working copy starts at svntest. Does it come down to the fact that it's smart enough to know that it is in the working copy?

Comment: If you specify the full path of the file to be committed `svn` is able to detect that the file is in a working copy. There's some metadata saved in *each* directory of the working copy tree (see `.svn` directory).

Answer (score 0):

may be issue with path

pass the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in `svn_commit_file()` function

```
svn_commit_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

based on this full physical path run svn commit command... probably work fine

thanks